# Chrome does not suggest strong password for google account itself

Tags: google-chrome

You know that Chrome has such ability of suggestion strong password in registration or password reset/change forms. But this does not work when I want to change or reset my Google account password, so the password suggestion option is not displayed in context menu unlike the others. Is it right or bug or what else?